# AWS Cloudwatch Math Expressions: draw null / empty

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create a dashboard widget that says "if a metric sample count is less than certain number, don't draw the graph".

The only Math expression that seem promising is `IF`, however the value can only be a metric or a scalar. I'm trying to find a way to draw a null/no data point/empty instead.

Any way?

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html#using-IF-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudWatch will drop data points that are not numbers (NaN, +Infinity, -Infinity) when graphing the data. Also, metric math will evaluate basic operations in the expression. You can divide by zero to get non-number value.

So you can do something like this to trick it into dropping the values you don't want:

- Have your metric in the graph as `m1`.
- Have the sample count of your metric in the graph as `m2`.
- Add an `IF` function to drop data points if the sample count is lower than some number (10 in this example): `IF(m2 < 10, 1/0, m1)`
- Disable m1 and m2 on the graph and only show the expression.

Comment: CloudWatch will show ⚠️ for metrics that return `1/0`. Instead, you can arrange your `IF` to succeed, and omit the third parameter, like `IF(m2 >= 10, m1)`. This will omit the value from the chart without displaying an error.